# firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP return an Object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a web project with Firebase.
I call:

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

and it returns:

```
{.sv: "timestamp"}
```

How will I get time of Firebase server with javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This snippet from the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps) shows how to *set* a timestamp:

```
var userLastOnlineRef = firebase.database().ref("users/joe/lastOnline");
userLastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

To also have the value available in your code, you need to listen for the value:

```
userLastOnlineRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

You'll see the value event fire twice (on the device that sets the value): once for the initial client-side estimate of the timestamp and once for the actual value from the server.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I had to do:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Source:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue

Comment: This one worked for me, the other solutions did not.

Comment: When using firestore this is the solution. The `database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` solution is for the realtime database.

Answer (score 3):

It's expected that you will use `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in data that's written to the Firebase database. It's a placeholder for the actual time on the server and will be replaced when the server receives and writes the data.

You will see the actual timestamp value when you read the data from the database or when any listeners you have might have already configured fire (for `child_added`, `child_changed`, or `value` events etc.).

It's explained in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue):

> ```
> {TIMESTAMP: non-null Object}
> ```
>
> A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) as determined by the Firebase servers.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some more to answer from @cartant:

`admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` returns a non-null Object and is a **placeholder** value for auto-populating the current timestamp. **It doesn't contain the actual timestamp**. The database will replace this placeholder when it will execute the command.

It works as you expect when you are using it inside a `database.ref` but outside of it is just an useless Object.

See this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484575/6490721) for more.

Comment: How do i get the actual value if I want to return it as part of the response?

Answer (score 1):

Version 9, based on [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp):

```
import { updateDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, 'objects', 'some-id');

// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
const updateTimestamp = await updateDoc(docRef, {
    timestamp: serverTimestamp()
});
```