# Firebase not converting '{".sv": "timestamp"}' to server timestamp

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Here is a Screenshot of written document.]

What am I missing here ?

Code looks something like:

```
localDocument['a3'] = {".sv": "timestamp"};
```

where `a3` is supposed to be server timestamp field in this document.

Comment: Refer to the [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907151/flutter-firestore-server-side-timestamp) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214593/firebase-database-servervalue-timestamp-return-an-object).

Comment: `{".sv": "timestamp"}` is the sentinel value for Realtime Database. I'm pretty sure Firestore uses another sentinel. Any reasons you can't use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp?